# PowerAutomate-SharePoint List: invalid response for workflow operation 'Create_new_folder'

Tags: list, json

I have been working on this list and flow for a few weeks now and it took me a while to figure out how I could extract an attachment from the SharePoint List and send it to a newly and automatically created folder (through PowerAutomate) in Teams. I did some tests and it finally worked - the folders were create with their respective files through the designated path.

However, for some reason, I keep getting this message now:
[image]

I haven't touched this part of the flow in a while. Everything seems to be in order. I do have to add, though, that I have been working on the JSON in this specific SharePoint List but I don't know how this could have influenced this new problem.

Comment: have you verified whether there are any invalid inputs in your `Create new folder` action? It seems like the issue might be caused by passing an incorrect JSON object to the action, resulting in the error being thrown.